# TeamCity - GitVersion generates the build number unexpected

Tags: teamcity, gitversion

I have the git commits and the tags as below

[image]

The tag of the latest commit is 12.0.0-beta.6. When I run GitVersion, the result is as below

[image]

So the build number on TeamCity should be 12.0.0-beta.6, but I don't know why the GitVersion   generates build number 12.0.0-beta.6+8 on TeamCity.

[image]

My build steps are as below

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why GitVersion generates the redundant "+8" after the FullSemVer?
How to remove this dedundant "+8"?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+8` is [metadata](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/version-increments#approach) and not actually part of the version number. In [the documentation for the version variables](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/variables), `BuildMetaData` is described as:

> The build metadata, usually representing number of commits since the `VersionSourceSha`.

You can see the same value `8` exposed as `CommitsSinceVersionSouce` and this should increase with every commit made to the branch since its "version source", which in this case is the tag `12.0.0-beta.6` made on commit `549a1d`.

The metadata does not increase with every build, but with every commit. I can see how the current language is confusing and the name `BuildMetaData` does not help. Since `BuildMetaData` is an exposed variable, we can't change its name, but I've submitted [a PR that will hopefully clarify its documentation](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/pull/2984).

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully and **understand** at least part of [GitVerson docs](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/version-increments#approach) (paragraphs 1+2)

**The shortest possible extraction**

> GitVersion will increment *the metadata* for **each build** so you can tell
> builds apart. For example, `1.0.0+5` followed by `1.0.0+6`. It is important
> to note that build metadata *is not part of the semantic version; it is
> just metadata*!

Comment: I don't think this "+8" is the incremented metadata because it's always "+8" regardless of how many builds I trigger.